# hEvent member in OVERLAPPED Win32 structure

Tags: windows, winapi, visual-c++, overlapped-io

When asynchronous I/O (or "overlapped" I/O in Win32 jargon) is used, we need to deal with the `OVERLAPPED` structure and his `hEvent` member. If the I/O function will delay the read or write operation, we will get an `ERROR_IO_PENDING` error code, then we will wait the asynchronous operation to complete with a `WaitForXxxEvent` function, then we will call `GetOverlappedResult`.

However, if the I/O operation is immediately completed, we will not get `ERROR_IO_PENDING`, and in a read operation our read buffer will be filled immediately. But what about the `OVERLAPPED::hEvent` member? Will it be set to signaled state? I've not found a clear statement about that.

This question may seem pointless (why deal with the event if I know that the operation is already completed?), however I have a library that mimics the overlapped pattern and I need to have the same exact behavior.

---

As pointed by [edgar.holleis](https://stackoverflow.com/users/24937/edgar-holleis) in [his comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2511690/hevent-member-in-overlapped-win32-structure#comment54073084_2511763), [Raymond Chen](https://stackoverflow.com/users/902497/raymond-chen) explained this in his blog: [Link](https://web.archive.org/web/20140516071457/http://blogs.msdn.com:80/b/oldnewthing/archive/2014/02/06/10497096.aspx)

> **If an asynchronous I/O completes synchronously, is the hEvent in the OVERLAPPED structure signaled anyway?**
>
> Yes.
>
> When an I/O completes (whether synchronously or asynchronously), the
> event is signaled and completion status notifications are queued. The
> `Get­Overlapped­Result/Ex` function can be used to wait on an I/O that
> has already completed; it will merely return immediately. If you ask
> Has­Overlapped­Io­Completed whether the I/O has completed, and the I/O
> completed synchronously, it will correctly report, "Yeah, of course it
> completed. Heck, it completed a long time ago!"
>
> In other words, you can logically treat the case of an asynchronous
> I/O request completing synchronously as if it had completed
> asynchronously. It just completes asynchronously before you even
> blinked.

Comment: The event will also be signaled if the operation completes immediately. It was tested with named pipes in Windows 7.

Answer (score 2):

No it won't.  It took me ages to figure that one out the hard way ;)

Comment: That's counter-intuitive... the documentation says that I/O functions that accept an OVERLAPPED will always reset the event (so we don't have to manually reset it before the call), and that the event will be signaled when the I/O operation will be completed. Now, if the I/O operation completes immediately, the event should be signaled when the I/O function return TRUE... hmm...

Comment: I'm not going to say it confused the f**k out of me but I had MAJOR problems with the hEvent.  In the end I just sacked it off and went with a "WaitForIOCompletion" function that would just sleep till it completed.

Comment: @edgar.holleis thanks, you should add this as a full answer